# Salesforce Analytics API runningUser

Tags: api, salesforce, analytics, dashboard, force.com

I want to be able to retrieve my dashboard resource through analytics api but setting the query parameter runningUser as another user id, that way get different result depending on the user running the dashboard. From salesforce documentation  [analytics api dashboard results resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_dashboard_results_resource.htm) looks like it should work but it doesn't, each time I make a request the dashboard is ran by the user set from the force.com platform UI without respecting the query param.

Endpoint: `/vXX.X/analytics/dashboards/dashboardID?runningUser=runningUserID&filter1=filter1ID&filter2=filter2ID&filter3=filter3ID`

Did someone face the same issue? maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Preview config from the dashboard edit page, mark the following checkboxes : 'The dashboard viewer' and 'Let dashboard viewers choose whom they view the dashboard as' that way the query parameter 'runningUser' will take effect when running dashboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview config from the dashboard edit page, mark the following checkboxes : 'The dashboard viewer' and 'Let dashboard viewers choose whom they view the dashboard as' that way the query parameter 'runningUser' will take effect when running dashboards.